# Access global variable inside polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I need to access javascript variable inside Polymer object. Tried accessing that variable inside ready function but nothing comes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="elements/my-app.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>
    <script>
      var messages = []
      var messages_count = {{ messages|length }};

      {% for message in messages %}
          var message = "{{ message.text }}"
          messages.push(message)
      {% endfor %}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Update: Added my-app html file

```
<dom-module is="my-app">
   <script>
     Polymer({
       is: "my-app",
     })
   </script>
</dom-module>
```

And How do I access the `messages` in `my-app` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can access them just like you access them in any other javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="wecomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
  <script>
    var message = "Hi";
  </script>
</body>

</html>


<dom-module is="my-app">
  <template></template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "my-app",
      attached: function() {
        alert(message);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```